# How to use tsCV() with MAPA?

Tags: r, model, time-series, cross-validation

I want to use tsCV() with Multiple Aggregation Prediction Algorithm (MAPA) and ETS, and when I was trying to run the following code, all the e2 returns are NA values. I don't know whether I wrote the wrong statements or it just cannot work with mapa()?

```
 fets <- function(y,h) {
    forecast(ets(y), h = 8)
  }
 fmapa <- function(y,fh) {
    mapa(y, fh = 8, conf.lvl=c(0.8,0.95))
  }

 e1 <- tsCV(yt, fets, h=8)
 e2 <- tsCV(yt, fmapa, h=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1. The forecasting function must return an object of class `forecast`. See the help file for `tsCV()`. The `MAPA` package does not return `forecast` objects, so you need to create it from the output. In fact, the only thing that really matters here is that the object is a list with an element called `mean` containing the forecasts.
2. The forecasting function must have an argument `h` describing the number of forecast horizons. Renaming it to `fh` will cause problems.

A less serious problem is that the `h` and `fh` arguments in your functions are completely ignored as you override them in the body of the function.

Here is an example that works.

```r
library(MAPA)

fets <- function(y, h = 8) {
  forecast(ets(y), h = h)
}
fmapa <- function(y, h = 8) {
  result <- mapa(y, fh = h, conf.lvl = c(0.8, 0.95))
  list(mean = result$outfor)
}

yt <- ts(rnorm(20), frequency = 4)

e1 <- tsCV(yt, fets, h = 8)
e2 <- tsCV(yt, fmapa, h = 8)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>